# Http Connection Flush several times on Wireless connection and only one time on EDGE and 3G

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I want to make an http connection that flushes several times like the code below:

```
           int length100 = 1000;
           int position = 0;
           while (position < length) {
                try {
                    os.write(postDataBytes, position, length100);
                    position += length100;
                    int location = position * 100 / length;
                    gaugeField.setValue(location);
                    os.flush();
                }
            }
```

This code works on Wireless connection. But when testing it on EDGE and 3G, the code flushes only once and when trying to write using the `os.write(...);` an exception is thrown `StreamConnection: Stream Closed`

Any Help or Idea?

Comment: on line os.write(postDataBytes, position, length100); - what is length100 ?

Comment: @Signare the question is updated

Comment: Have you tried a SocketConnection?

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota I didn't, I want to make it work with HTTP not socket ...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP connections aren't typically interactive.  While I agree, for a functioning network stack, it should be possible to call flush() along the way, I don't see any hardship imposed by removing the call entirely.

Why do you need to call flush() multiple times on the same request?

Comment: Because I need to calculate the percentage of bytes that are sent already. Using the write() method isn't enough because the only function that sends the data is flush() or getResponseCode(). Right?

Comment: No. A write may cause data to be sent (when the a buffer is filled for example), and depending on the underlying communications a flush may not. The flush will force the data to be "written out" but doesn't guarantee that "written out" is the same as transmitted. For simple IO semantics like a file connection that is probably true, or not. On most flavours of Unix even simple file output, a flush will not guarantee a write to the file system. I would not make that assumption about an http connection on a BlackBerry without some documentation to point to.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your response, Well you may be right that .write() may send the data, but the testing revealed the opposite. Even with no connection, the .write() is passed and I get 99% completed, but the flush don't send the data. In addition, with internet connection, when a file is about 500KB for example, the .write successfully do the job within 2 seconds for example and i get 99% but the flush() or the getResponseCode() takes 1 or 2 minutes. So to force the data to be "written out" i want something to flush the data to the server and not just write the bytes to the OutputStream

Comment: getResponseCode requires a server to process the request and return a response so that time will include server latency as well as round trip and buffer time. I think you are basing your premise on observed rather than documented behaviour. A network connection implemented over hardline or Wi-Fi may transmit on flush() in almost all implementations, but that doesn't mean you should assume it will in all, and especially in the mobile wireless world. Assuming behaviour based on observation rather than knowing behaviour based on specs and docs is a bad first step for a programmer.